# Feature Activation Routing Workflows - SharePoint 2010 (en-US)

Tags: 2010, feature-activation

We get an error message: "the feature with the ID {3bc0c1e1-b7d5-4e82-afd7-9f7e59b60409} must be activated."
Does somebody know how to activate this feature. I can't find it in central administration or in site actions.
I think it's an hidden feature, but i no idea how to activate it.

Answer (score 2):

It is **Routing Workflows - SharePoint 2010 (en-US**) feature which needs to be activated at Site collection level.It is a hidden feature.
You can activate it using powershell:

```
Enable-SPFeature -identity {3bc0c1e1-b7d5-4e82-afd7-9f7e59b60409} -URL http://yoursite
```